# Setting page delay in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I could open the site in Firefox by running my test case script. The opened page does not wait till I enter userid and password. As I start typing userid, the opened page closes. 
What could be best way to set delay, allowing end-user to enter user id and password.

Comment: You'll have to show us some code. There's nothing you should have to do. Please create an [mcve](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 6):

The question is not clear enough to answer. however in RF you can use Sleep to put some Delay before executing the next step like Close Browser, Stop Process,Close Window,etc.. so put some Sleep before the page/browser close Keyword.

```
Sleep    10s
Sleep    2 minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add wait for a particular element which must be visible in the loaded page.
for this you can use:
Wait Until Element is Visible      locator

IF the page takes more time to load you can have a retry before the wait as:

Wait Until Keyword Succeeds   retry   retry_interval   Wait Until Element is Visible      locator